# Thread 1: SIGNAL SIGABRT; What do I do?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

I was trying to get a notification to pop up, but I keep getting **Thread 1: SIGNAL SIGABRT** What should I do? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func pushNotification(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var AlertView = UIAlertController(title: "Time for your call!", message: "Press go to continue", preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    AlertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(AlertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: code is ok - you must have issue somewhere else, how is `pushNotification()` invoked? and pls use lower camel case for variables `var alertView`

Comment: `pushNotification()` is invoked from a button on the Main.Storyboard

Comment: it's might be a problem with binding outlet action - check connections inspector and remove bad binds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error generally happens when you have created an outlet for an object on your storyboard, then decided for whatever reason to delete that code and then replace it with a different outlet, without removing the connection on the storyboard. The result is that the compiler looks for the original outlet that you assigned to the object but cannot find it (because you have deleted it!).

Happily, the solution is relatively quick. Go to the connections inspector for the object (it is the symbol with an arrow pointing right in a circle in the right hand panel of XCode) and you will probably find that there are more outlets listed there than you thought were attached to the object. Delete all the ones that reference functions you have deleted and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode check *Connections Inspector* of the problematic view controller, next check *Received Actions* if it has wrong/outdated bindings, check *Outlets* too.
[image]

Here I created `pushNotificationOldVersion` bound it to the button's *Touch Up Inside* action then in code changed method's name to `pushNotificationNewVersion` - but it is not automatically updated the binding in *Storyboard*